# Return value from middle of `do` (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, architecture, functional-programming

I have a list of I/O functions to run in a game, but need to collect the value from a function somewhere in the middle of the `do`

```
(defn setup-steps [game-state]
  (do (io/clear-screen)
      (print-welcome-message)
      (initial-setup) ;; value to be collected
      (io/clear-screen)
      (io/print-board game-state)))
```

Is there a smart way to return the value from somewhere in the middle of a `do`?

Down the line, I am using the return value of `setup-steps` to update an atom, like so:

```
(defn game-loop [game]
  (while (:game-in-progress? @game)

     ;; Here is where I am using the results
    (->> (s-io/setup-steps @game) (state/updater game))

    (while (:game-in-progress? @game)
      (->> (m-io/turn-steps @game) (state/updater game)))
    (->> (eg-io/end-game-steps @game) (state/updater game)))
  (eg-io/exit-game))
```

Where

```
(defn updater
  "Updates the game state.
  This is the only place where the game atom is modified."
  [game update-params]
  (swap! game merge update-params))
```

I'm sure you could write a macro for this, but I don't really understand macros yet.

And maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way... Is it more idiomatic to dow the `swap!`ing inside `setup-steps`?

Comment: You could also look into using `loop` and `recur` (keeping your state in a `loop` binding) instead of `while` with an atom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason you can't assign the result in a `let` and return it at the end of the function?

```
(defn setup-steps [game-state]
  (io/clear-screen)
  (print-welcome-message)
  (let [v (initial-setup)] ;; value to be collected
    (io/clear-screen)
    (io/print-board game-state)
    v))
```

**EDIT**: Got rid of the redundant `do` that Ryan Asensio mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have in there, but it just seems so hacky!

Comment: The `do` is redundant/implicit here too.

Comment: Nice. Taking the `do` out makes it pretty acceptable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally the only way to do this is with `let`, as clartaq shows. But if you find this distasteful there are a number of ways you could wrap this up in a macro to make it prettier to look at and also more clear about what you're doing. Here is the simplest one, which I like to call `returning`:

```
(defmacro returning [x & more]
  `(let [x# ~x]
     (do ~@more)
     x#))

(defn foo []
  (x)
  (y)
  (returning (z)
    (a)
    (b)))
```

The `do` in `returning` is of course superfluous, but I think it's still useful to emphasize that `more` is evaluated only for side effects.

Comment: It seems to me also (try ... (finally ...)) can do. Any reason to prefer let? Thanks.

Comment: The most obvious reason is that try/finally is about exceptions, and you're not trying to do anything with exceptions at all: it's clearly misleading, and semantically wrong. But also, it's not equivalent: `(try (f) (finally (g)))` will execute `(g)` even if `(f)` throws an exception, unlike `(let [x (f)] (g) x)`.